# "Supposedly" in Japanese

Tags: expressions

How do you express in Japanese that something is generally claimed to have a certain property without positioning yourself to clearly as to the veracity of the claim?

For example, how would you express the following sentence in Japanese:

> Reliquaries are the supposed bones of saints.

Comment: ....と思われる or ...と推測｛すいそく｝される...etc?

Comment: I like "〜という説があります". Also ...らしい

Comment: Also, maybe not applicable to your example, but perhaps relevant to your question, そう has a possible connotation similar to "supposedly" (reporting hearsay).

Comment: と噂される・という噂もある・という言い伝えもある  are other more distant possibilities. And to clarify what @WeirdlyCheezy said, ～だそうだ

Comment: Also ...とされる for "allegedly" which may fit better in certain cases (http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q141925824)

Answer (score 4):

I think all the comments provide good examples. In my experience though, the most commonly used in this situation is also the simplest one: 言われている  (or 思われている as well, like in the first comment that I initially somehow missed).

Checking on [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/supposedly) for example, you can find the following example:

*He's supposedly 85 years old*: 彼は 85 歳だといわれている.

Now, obviously this is just one example since as many people commented there are other ways to express that. However, as I said in my experience this is very commonly used. After all, if you think about it, "it is supposed that"  and "it is being said that" bear a similar, if not the same, meaning.

In this fashion your sentence could be translated as:

> 聖遺物{せいいぶつ}は聖者{せいじゃ}の骨{ほね}だと言われている。

EDIT: I changed the word 舎利 I originally used for reliquaries with  聖遺物 as suggested by @Brandon in a comment. I agree that this is a more appropriate choice in this context..supposedly. :)

Comment: 舎利 is strongly connected to Buddhism, no? And saints are (often) Abrahamic so it seems an odd, if interesting, fit. Who's to say though without any more context.

Comment: Yeah I had exactly the same feeling. However, I was not able to find any more appropriate word.

Comment: If we're going with an  Abrahamic context, 聖遺物？

Comment: Seems exactly correct. There is even a wiki page: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%81%96%E9%81%BA%E7%89%A9 that seems to confirm that this is what we are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

“Supposedly” can be translated in various ways depending on the context, for example:

> 多分, 恐らく, 想像するに, and 推測するところ.

[Oxford Advanced English Learners Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/reliquary?q=reliquary) defines "reliquary" as:

> a container in which a relic of a holy person is kept.

Kenkyusha's Readers Plus English Japanese Dictionary defines "Reliquary" as 聖骨箱.

If we follow both of the above definitions, the given line would be translated as:

> 聖骨箱は聖人（ら）の遺骨を納めていると思われる。

舎利 means bones, but it's specifically applied to the bones of Buddha and Buddhist saints' bones.

Answer (score 0):

The word [supposedly] is often used in an ironic (slightly sarcastic) manner.

Both of Wiktionary's sample sentences contain this idea.

> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supposedly
>
> - People from other planets have supposedly visited Earth in flying saucers.
> - According to your testimony, you were supposedly at home watching TV when the murder occurred.
>
> Synonyms  ==  allegedly,  purportedly

2 of 11 sample sentences in Alc contain this idea.

> http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=supposedly
>
> - supposedly egalitarian society ===
>     建前｛たてまえ｝としての平等｛びょうどう｝主義｛しゅぎ｝の社会
> - cheat someone by charging $__ for supposedly free visits === 
>     《イ》サイトの閲覧｛えつらん｝を無料｛むりょう｝だとして（人）をだまして＿ドルを課金｛かきん｝する

The latter half of Alc's definitions contain this (ironic) idea: [ 建前｛たてまえ｝上は［としては］、一応｛いちおう｝は、一般｛いっぱん｝に信じられているところでは、～といわれている ]

Another way to express this idea is [... とされている ] or  [ ...ということになっている ]